# Facebook API for ad accounts. How to use time_range parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook graph api for my ad account to get the insights of a specific date. I believe date is the correct parameter to use. Here is Facebook's documentation for ad account insights https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/

Here is the url I am attempting to use:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/act_ACCOUNT_ID/insights?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&time_range={"since":"2016-08-09","until":"2016-08-09"}&fields=account_id%2Cspend%2Cimpressions%2Ctotal_actions&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey
```

This is the response I get:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Must be a date representation in the format YYYY-MM-DD","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HEFP4SeNfWa"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know concerning the single or double quotes. For me, the single quotes worked this way :

```
act_account_id/insights?time_range={'since':'2016-10-17','until':'2016-10-17'}&fields=reach
```

However, using Google Apps SCript and UrlFetchApp.fetch method, I had to use encodeURIComponent on the time range parameters to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to use this is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/act_ACCOUNT_ID?fields=insights.time_range({"since":"2016-08-09","until":"2016-08-09"}){account_id,spend,impressions,total_actions}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&method=get&pretty=0&sdk=joey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
act_account_id/insights?time_range={'since':'2016-10-17','until':'2016-10-17'}&fields=reach
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's wrong with the time range in the original question? Is it the use of double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: single or double shouldn't matter as long as you url encode it

Comment: Unable to fetch data for inactive advert-id....How to fetch inactive advert  insight detail..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too. This is URL encoded:

time_range=%7B'since':'2020-04-06','until':'2020-04-09'%7D

but keep in mind that above line only works with the combination of:

time_increment=1